# Is this someone trying to hack the server?

Tags: spam, hacking

I keep seeing the following coming up in my nginx and Apache server log files as a 400:

```
() { :; }; /bin/ping -c 3 x.x.x.x
```

x.x.x.x is different IPs. Does this look like a hacker trying to find a hole into the server? We have IP blocking facilities, but I don't want to do that if its genuine.

The full log file entry, is:

```
207.150.177.200 - - [25/Sep/2015:08:51:02 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 226 "() { :; }; /bin/ping -c 3 82.118.236.247" "-"
```

Comment: Don't ban the IP.  **Don't** feed these logs into an analysis db without sanitising them.

Comment: @MadHatter - the SQL is sanitised before going onto a DB :) We use mysql placeholder, to stop any kinda nasty SQL injections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are trying. And failing.

You can tell that they are failing by looking at the return code -`400 - bad request` means that your server is basically saying "No way I'm going to let you do that". Which, in this context, is a good thing.

Comment: Good to know :) We are getting about 50-100 requests a day (from generally 10-15 different IPs), all trying to find unsecured WP plugins, phpmyadmin, other admin tools, or just backdoors. I'm blocking them as soon as they show up (as no point wasting resources on them!) ... but its a total PITA!

Comment: In my experience, this is going to taper off once this particular exploit isn't the latest and most interesting thing anymore. (Of course, it'll be replaced by something else...)

Comment: Yeah - they are certainly persistent! Most of the IPs hitting us are blacklisted already on other sites like projecthoneypot, which at least gives use evidence they are persistently trying to get into people servers

Comment: Most of those IPs will be of botnets - groups of computers that have been compromised, so the owners are most likely not even aware of what his happening. These attempts are botnet owners trying to add to their collections.

Answer (score 7):

I have a lot of respect for Jenny's answer, but I thought I had to add this:

It's an attempt to do a [shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) attack (with grateful thanks to Iain for pointing this out).  Provided you've patched your server against this vulnerability, the web server returns a `400`, which takes it *microseconds* of CPU, and thinks no further on the matter.

But you write that you're "*blocking them as soon as they show up (as no point wasting resources on them!)*".  May I point out that you're wasting a *ton* of resources on them - to wit, your time?

Trying to play whack-a-mole with the exploit *du jour* on every application on your system is **not** a good use of your time!  The right thing to do is - having established that you're not vulnerable to them - to ignore them, let them be logged, and screen them out in post-processing.  The best use of your time is keeping ruthlessly up with your patches!

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to make my system just ignore them when it shows up with that particular command (so we don't see it in the error tracker). That way, we won't waste resources on the firewall for them, and as you said, we are more than safe (as they are trying to exploit something that doesn't affect us). I have also updated our tracking system, so we ignore 400 errors completely (as said before, the server is doing what it should be here - so no point wasting time on them)

Comment: Isn't that a [shellshock](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/) attack rather than SQL injection ?

Comment: @Iain - thanks, that does look like it could be. I've just run the test command they suggested on there, and it looks like we are nice and secure from that vulnerability :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby When I've been working with public webservers, I'd have a script that would give me stats from the logs. All these logs from attacks did was give me a warm fuzzy feeling that my systems were at least not vulnerable to that particular exploit; that's all the time I wasted on them.